# How can i press a button in headerbar and do things in window in vala

Tags: button, window, gtk3, vala

How to make a button in headerbar and do things in window i've tried:

```
public class headerbar : Gtk.HeaderBar {
    construct {
        title = "Quiz";
        subtitle = "You can solve this!";
        show_close_button = true;
        Gtk.Button button = new Gtk.Button.with_label ("Quit");
        button.get_style_context ().add_class ("suggested-action");
        button.set_valign (Gtk.Align.CENTER);
        button.clicked.connect (() => {
            var label = new Gtk.Label ("Hi");
            main.add (label);
            label.show ();
        });
        pack_start (button);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a sample as follow, hope it could help you:

```cs
public class AppTitleBar : Gtk.HeaderBar {
    private Gtk.Button m_new_tab_button;
    private Gtk.Box m_app_title_gui_box;
    private Gtk.MenuButton m_main_menu_button;

    public weak Workbench workbench { get; construct; }

    public AppTitleBar (Workbench workbench) {
        Object ( workbench: workbench );
    }

    construct {
        set_show_close_button (true);

        this.build_title_bar_layout();
    }

    public void add_new_tab(Widget title_widget)
    {
        m_app_title_gui_box.pack_start(title_widget);
        title_widget.focus.connect(() => {
            this.update_tab_inactive_all();
            return true;
        });
    }

    public void update_tab_inactive_all()
    {
        m_app_title_gui_box.foreach ((widget) => {
            widget.set_opacity(0.3);
        });
    }

    public void remove_tab_widget(Widget tab_bar)
    {
        m_app_title_gui_box.remove(tab_bar);
    }

    private void build_title_bar_layout()
    {
        m_main_menu_button = new Gtk.MenuButton ();
        var menu_image = new Gtk.Image.from_icon_name ("open-menu-symbolic", Gtk.IconSize.BUTTON);
        m_main_menu_button.set_image (menu_image);
        m_main_menu_button.tooltip_text = ("Main Menu");

        // create title bar box
        m_app_title_gui_box = new Box(Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 2);

        // create add new tab button
        m_new_tab_button = new Gtk.Button.from_icon_name("list-add", Gtk.IconSize.BUTTON);
        m_new_tab_button.get_style_context ().add_class ("back-button");
        m_new_tab_button.valign = Gtk.Align.CENTER;
        m_new_tab_button.always_show_image = true;
        m_new_tab_button.can_focus = false;
        m_new_tab_button.action_name = WorkbenchActions.ACTION_PREFIX + WorkbenchActions.ACTION_TAB_NEW;
        m_new_tab_button.has_tooltip = true;
        m_new_tab_button.tooltip_text = "Open a new connection (Ctrl+N)";

        this.pack_end(m_main_menu_button);
        this.pack_start(m_app_title_gui_box);
        this.pack_start(m_new_tab_button);
    }
}
```